# sql query select date equal rows from datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select the row when date equal particular date, where as the TIMESTAMP  column contain datetime.

This works fine,

```
select USERNAME from ACCESSACTIVITY where UPPER(LOCATION)=UPPER('remote-PC')and TIMESTAMP = STR_TO_DATE('28-05-2016 01:00:00','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

where as when I avoid time, it doesn't work.

```
select USERNAME from ACCESSACTIVITY where UPPER(LOCATION)=UPPER('remote-PC')and TIMESTAMP = STR_TO_DATE('28-05-2016 ','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the wildcards.
Try this:

```
select USERNAME from ACCESSACTIVITY where UPPER(LOCATION)=UPPER('remote-PC')and DATE(TIMESTAMP) = STR_TO_DATE('28-05-2016 ','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
select USERNAME from ACCESSACTIVITY where UPPER(LOCATION)=UPPER('remote-PC')and TIMESTAMP LIKE STR_TO_DATE('28-05-2016 ','%d-%m-%Y')+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `timestamp` is stored as a `datetime`, then use inequality:

```
select USERNAME
from ACCESSACTIVITY
where UPPER(LOCATION)=UPPER('remote-PC') and
     TIMESTAMP >= DATE('2016-05-28') AND
     TIMESTAMP < DATE('2016-05-29');
```

This allows the database engine to use an index on `TIMESTAMP` if an appropriate index is available.